# Controller method parameter  is empty when I redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Slots(Slots slots, ICollection<int> jobNos)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(new SlotsViewModel() { JobNos = jobNos, Slots = slots });

        //
        // Do stuff
        //

        return View("MyResults", jobNos);
    }

    public ActionResult MyResults(ICollection<int> jobs)
    {
        return View(jobs);
    }
```

However, this does not work.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Slots(Slots slots, ICollection<int> jobNos)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(new SlotsViewModel() { JobNos = jobNos, Slots = slots });

        //
        // Do stuff
        //

        return RedirectToAction("MyResults", new { jobs = jobNos });
    }

    public ActionResult MyResults(ICollection<int> jobs)
    {
        return View(jobs);
    }
```

When I redirect to the new action the ICollection jobs is empty when it should have a count > 0.

Anyone got an idea why redirecting would empty the collection?

Comment: Because redirecting does not do a POST; it does a GET.

Comment: Excellent Robert.. I had the same error, and I didn't know that, it was GET, that happens when we use redirectToAction..Good Work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` returns a 302 response to the client browser and thus the browser will make a new **GET** requst to the specified URL.

In this case, If you really want to pass the collection between these two (stateless) HTTP requests, You need some temp storage mechanism like `TempData`

```
TempData["Jobs"] =jobNos ;
return RedirectToAction("MyResults");
```

And Read it in the other ActionMethod

```
public ActionResult MyResults()
{
  var model=TempData["Jobs"] as List<int>;
  return View(model);
}
```

`TempData` uses `Session` object behind the scene to store the data. But once the data is read the data is terminated.